# Where to find Outlook Web Access (OWA)/Exchange Webmail?

Tags: iis, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, webmail

We're using Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit and Exchange Server 2010, and I'm the administrator, but we had a contractor set up the server, so I'm not sure what some of our settings are.

Now I'm trying to access Outlook Web Access (OWA)/Exchange Webmail using web browser. It's all in-house on the LAN. We have a computer that doesn't have Outlook installed and just wanted to be able to access webmail using a web browser. On our old server we just pointed the browser to `\\CompanyName\Exchange\UserName` or something like that.

I assume there's a setting somewhere I can check. I don't want to change it. I just want to know where to point the browser. Where do I find that setting and where do I point the browser to use webmail?

I've been searching the net for an answer but just found this:

> Get your login information. Your network administrator or IT department can provide this information along with support to teach you how to access Exchange Webmail.

Sorry, I *am* the admin, but I don't know the answer to this one.

Comment: Is the [client access role](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998629(v=exchg.141).aspx) installed/enabled?

Comment: Well I was able to log in using donrosco's answer so I guess the answer is yes. And thanks for the link!

Comment: Yeah, I *love* those "contact your administrator" error messages.  Make me want to go punch the nearest developer in the throat. :)

Comment: But now, thanks to ServerFault, I once again have the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should default to the exchange server's name with OWA on the end:

https://ExchangeServer/OWA

Does that work?

If not, try it with your domain as well:

https://ExchangeServer.domain.local/OWA

Answer (score 5):

The default path, as others have mentioned, is `https://servername/OWA`.

If the default doesn't work, or if you simply want to double-check how the server is actually configured, you can use the [Get-OwaVirtualDirectory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998588(v=exchg.141).aspx) command in the Exchange Management Shell.

Also, here's some documentation about managing Outlook Web App: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996373(v=exchg.141).aspx.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, and/or to help out the next guy who has this problem and doesn't have his OWA server at the default virtualpath, you can find out through the IIS Manager on the server hosting Outlook Web App.

Navigate to the `OWA` site, check the `Advanced Settings` to get your OWA Virtual path, and append that to the server name and/or whatever DNS aliases you have for your OWA server to access webmail.

[image]